# how to change the display days' names in angular - bootstrap calendar?

Tags: angular, calendar

I use angular bootstrap calendar and I want to change the display days' names to another lanuage.
How can I do this?

This is the code:

```
<mwl-calendar-month-view [viewDate]="viewDate" [events]="events" (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)" (eventClicked)="eventClick($event)">
</mwl-calendar-month-view>
```

Comment: Did you have a thorough look through [the documentation](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/docs/injectables/CalendarDateFormatter.html) of the component that you are using? Maybe you could find something helpful there.

Comment: I looked there, I didnt see anything helpful for me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the developer has implemented the pipe functionality. Pipes are used to format a variety of data and you can find a lot of examples in the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).
Regarding the calendar, the developer also describes how to use pipes in the calendar. Right here: https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/docs/pipes/CalendarDatePipe.html#info

Comment: Thanks!!! It works!! I added this pipe: 
`{{ viewDate | calendarDate:(view + 'ViewTitle'):'Es'}}`
 and  in the .ts:
`import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';`
`import localeEs from '@angular/common/locales/Es';`
`registerLocaleData(localeEs);`
 `locale: string = "Es";`
Thank you !!